# Is there documentation to find the inheritance tree of a WPF or .NET Class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance

I need to find out for example if PropertyGrid or PropertyInspectorView are inherited from DependencyObject.
But I can't find documentation online that would let me go up an inheritance tree for any given class in .NET or WPF.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If it's a class that comes with .net, all inheritance details are in the MSDN documentation for each class. If it's a third party control, look to that controls website.  If you're talking about `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid`, it doesn't inherit from `DependencyObject` as the control is from WinForms and DO is from WPF.  If it's a PropertyGrid from a WPF toolkit, it probably does.

Comment: Literally the first Google hit for a search on PropertyGrid is the MSDN page, which displays the inheritance tree of the class.

Comment: Thanks to both of you , @Preston: it was around 2 a.m. that I posted the question and I guess I should not have been working at that time. Otherwise, I dont know how I missed that.  But thanks for the DependencyObject answer anyway. That was actually what I was wondering about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find this is to look at the official documentation over at MSDN. For [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) you can easily see that it doesn't inherit from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) by looking at the tree under "Inheritance Hierarchy".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the top of this page for `PropertyGrid`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx. You usually see the family tree up to this class on the official MSDN pages.